# how to add an index(path) to an array

Tags: iphone

i am wondering how its possible to add an index for a tableview to an array. i am trying to save this index to the array in order to be able to view it later. i just am interested in knowing how to save the index to the array. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a `NSMutableArray` and send it an `addObject:` message with the `NSIndexPath` as an argument.

Comment: This is very useful: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html - 
NSIndexPath's actual documentation does not contain the most useful bits!

Answer (score 0):

Same way you save anything to an array:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[myArray addObject:myIndexPath];
```

Comment: i tried this however im getting indexPath undeclared and confused by earlier erros bailing out...

 NSMutableArray *favorites =[[NSMutableArray favorites];
    [favorites addObject:indexPath];

Comment: There's no such class method as `[NSMutableArray favorites]`, and your double `[[` before that is a syntax error. What I said above is `NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array]`, which returns an autoreleased, empty NSMutableArray and assigns it to the pointer myArray.

Comment: yes sorry i fixed those errors without realizing i pasted them however after all this i get a crash everytime it reaches this code.
i have this code
 NSMutableArray *favorites = [NSMutableArray favorites];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPath];  
    [favorites addObject:indexPath];
and i put it in the viewDidLoad part of my second table view...
it crashes as soon as i click on that part. i have 2 hierachial table views with 2 detail view controllers.

Comment: So, again, there's no such thing as `[NSMutableArray favorites]`. You've now added another thing there's no such thing as, `[NSIndexPath indexPath]`. If you look in the console, you'll see it's dying because 'favorites' is an unrecognized selector on the class NSMutableArray.